# Как найти связанные таблицы MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Как найти связанные таблицы MySQL? Т.е. например, при удалении данных из одной таблицы удаляются данные из таблиц, у которых есть ограничение `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `owners_p_map` (
    ...
    CONSTRAINT `fk_owners_p_map_owners` FOREIGN KEY (`owners_id`) REFERENCES `owners` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Как можно по названию таблицы найти все такие таблицы, которые от неё зависят (т.е. у которых будут удаляться записи при удалении строки из этой таблицы, как в случае выше по названию `owners_p_map` найти `owners`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME) `table`
              , CONCAT(REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME) ref_table
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MyDataBase' 
  AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL;
```

А ещё лучше - аналогичный запрос к INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS:

```
SELECT CONCAT( CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
               '.',
               TABLE_NAME,
               ' REFERENCES ',
               UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
               '.',
               REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
               ' ON DELETE ',
               DELETE_RULE,
               ' ON UPDATE ',
               UPDATE_RULE
             ) `references`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='MyDataBase';
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я искала! Я бы только добавила во втором запросе ещё одно условие `AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName';`